# Why isn't WordPress respecting my HTML?

Tags: pages, html

I have a page in WordPress which includes the following valid HTML5:

```
<div id="bookLesson">
    <a href="lessons.php"><h1>Book your first lesson today</h1></a>
</div>
```

When it's rendering on the page, however, it looks like this:

```
<div id="bookLesson">
    <a href="lessons.php">
    <br />
    <h1>Book your first lesson today</h1>
    <p></a>
</div>
```

I'm editing in TEXT mode, so why is it adding `<br>` and `<p>` tags?

[image]

Comment: You should wrap your anchor inside your heading, not a heading inside your anchor.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic : [anchor tags can wrap block level elements](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/) valid in HTML5 (and frankly I am happy for the change).

Comment: Yup, you're dead right. But it would fix the issues without having to remove the `wpautop` filter.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Why would I want wpautop enabled? All it does is turn carriage returns into <p> and <br> tags. I have zero need or interest in that, and I'd have exactly the same problem even if I wrote it in XHTML or HTML4.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. You just need to add the following to your functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Disabling_the_filter

Answer (score 1):

The short explanation is that WP doesn't quite expect people to type valid HTML. It expects them to type text, maybe with HTML here and there.

Since browsers are not that forgiving, when it's time to output said text WP is attempting to smash it into something resembling real HTML. With various degree of success (`wpautop()` function you discovered).

While there is little that can be done to coherently explain everything that function does, in a nutshell it tries to turn text-y things into paragraphs of text and stay away from block-y things.

It considers `a` to be a text-y, and `h*` to be block-y. So when you try to put former outside of latter it gets confused and mangles things up, even though it's technically valid HTML.

Comment: Actually all it does it turns carriage returns into <p> and <br> tags. You can read exactly what wpautop does here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I know what it aims to accomplish. Explaining what _it actually technically does_ for function that mostly consists of poorly documented regular expressions is another matter entirely. :)